# Proving $f\in K(\beta)[X]$ irreducible iff $g\in K(\alpha)[X]$ irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $K\subset L$ a field extension and $\alpha,\beta\in L$ with minimal polynomials $f,g\in K[X]$.

How to show that $f\in K(\beta)[X]$ is irreducible iff $g\in K(\alpha)[X]$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the degree of the extension $K\subset K(\alpha, \beta)$.

Note that "$f\in K(\beta)[X]$ is irreducible" and "$g\in K(\alpha)[X]$ is irreducible" are *both* equivalent to that degree being $\deg(f)\deg(g)$.

Comment: I see from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/900889/109299 that the degree of both is equal, but why is that equivalent to the irreducibility of the minimal polynomials?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "the degree of both is equal." Note that the degree of the extension $K(\beta) \subset K(\alpha, \beta)$ is  the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K(\beta)$ this is $f$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible over $K(\beta)$. If it is not it's degree would be smaller.

Comment: @quid You say that '$[K(\alpha , \beta) : K]$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K(\beta)$ this is if and only if f is irreducible over $K(\beta)$. If it is not its degree would be smaller.' Could you better explain what you mean by this?

Comment: @MathWolf no. Let the degree of the fields  extension be $d$. Then $d = deg(f)deg(g)$ is equivalent to $f$ being irred. Same for $g$. Maybe also consult the duplicate.